# Indian passport holder - what to do in Hong Kong Transit area for 13 hours?

Tags: transit, hong-kong

I have a 13-hour layover in Hong Kong. I hold a passport issued at Hyderabad, India. Hong Kong does not issue transit visas for passport holders from India.

I am looking at things I could do in the transit area of the airport. Both my arrival and departure flights are from Terminal 1.

Can I go to Terminal 2, watch a couple of movies at the IMAX cinema and come back to terminal 1?

Any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: You don't need a transit visa: Indian passport holders can enter HK for up to 14 days visa-free as long as they pre-register online. http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/pre-arrival_registration_for_indian_nationals.html

Comment: You may go to town center by [airport express](http://www.mtr.com.hk/en/customer/services/airport_express_index.html).  And also try to [store your luggage](https://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/passenger/departure/all/baggage/left-baggage.html) in HKIA first.

Answer (score 2):

All flights depart from Terminal 1. Terminal 2 is only for check-in. If you stay in the transit area, airside, you can not go to T2. The IMAX cinema is landside. There's not much to do in HKIA, airside. You don't need a visa as an Indian citizen, just to register online before going. You might be better off entering HK and, depending on the schedule, go around visiting, or catching some sleep.